# Cannot Deserialize ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: serialization, json.net, iprincipal, iidentity

Given I create a claims identity and subsequently a principal.
Then I serialize the principal. Inspecting the json string I can confirm that the "Role" claim is there as well as the identity.

Deserializing it back results in an object with empty properties. The `.Claims` and `.Identity` is lost.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { new Claim("Role", "Admin") });
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(principal, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
ClaimsPrincipal deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClaimsPrincipal>(serialized); // The object has all properties empty
```

Question: How can I ensure the object is correctly deserialized?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue I guess the claimsPrinciple is a "protected" object that can't be "copied" that easy. Having a look into a Swagger-Generated code one solution could be creating new classes. Following a snippet from swagger-gen:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "9.13.15.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class ClaimsPrincipal 
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Claims", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Claim> Claims { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Identities", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ClaimsIdentity> Identities { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Identity", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public IIdentity Identity { get; set; }

        public string ToJson() 
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }

        public static ClaimsPrincipal FromJson(string data)
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClaimsPrincipal>(data);
        }

    }
```